# How to properly use iOS only components in React Native without error in Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to React Native and testing out PushNotificationIOS.  But the checkpermission call is giving me error on Android.

```
ExceptionsManager.js:61 Cannot read property 'checkPermissions' of undefined
```

I'm guessing this is because I need to only use the component on iOS.  How do I add a check of the OS to make the call only on iOS?

Here's my code:

```
  componentWillMount: function() {
    //--  need an OS check here??
    PushNotificationIOS.checkPermissions((data)=> {
      console.log("in comp will mount: checking for permission")
      console.log(data.alert)
      console.log(data.badge)
```

Comment: I agree with AKADER's answer below, but if in other places you need to perform one-off Platform checks you should check out the documentation for the Platform module. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would suggest is splitting that platform specific code in separate files.

> React Native will detect when a file has a .ios. or .android.
>   extension and load the relevant platform file when required from other
>   components.

```
MyFile.ios.js
MyFile.android.js
```

You can then require the component as follows:

```
const MyFile= require('./MyFile');
```

and use it like this

```
componentWillMount: function() {
    //--  it would call the logic of what ever platform was detected automatically
    MyFile.CallWhatEver();
```

And it will run the platform specific code.

Another way is the

Platform Module

> React Native provides a module that detects the platform in which the
>   app is running. You can use the detection logic to implement
>   platform-specific code. Use this option when only small parts of a
>   component are platform-specific.

```
if(Platform.OS === 'ios')
```

There is also a `platform.select` that can accept any value

```
const Component = Platform.select({
  ios: () => //function goes here,
  android: () => require('ComponentAndroid'),
})();
```

link
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html

Comment: Thanks!  Platform is what I need. :) will try the separate files when I have more platformspecific code.

Comment: Np. I wasn't sure if that was the only thing you needed so I recommended the first example. Please accept my answer :)